# Getting the wrong IP in C

Tags: c

I am writing a C program to find the class of an IP address. The issue with the code is that it is not displaying the correct IP address due to which the proper class is not being showed.

In the output negative values are being showed which are wrong.

The code compiles without any warnings or errors.

Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void extractIpAddress(unsigned char *sourceString,short *ipAddress)
{
     short len=0;
     char  oct[4]={0},cnt=0,cnt1=0,i,buf[5];

     len=strlen(sourceString);
     for(i=0;i<len;i++)
     {
          if(sourceString[i]!='.'){
          buf[cnt++] =sourceString[i];
     }
    if(sourceString[i]=='.' || i==len-1){
        buf[cnt]='\0';
        cnt=0;
        oct[cnt1++]=atoi(buf);
    }
}
ipAddress[0]=oct[0];
ipAddress[1]=oct[1];
ipAddress[2]=oct[2];
ipAddress[3]=oct[3];
}

int main()
{
     unsigned char ip[20]={0};
     short ipAddress[4];

     printf("Enter IP Address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx format): ");
     scanf("%s",ip);

     extractIpAddress(ip,&ipAddress[0]);

     printf("\nIp Address: %03d. %03d. %03d. 
     %03d\n",ipAddress[0],ipAddress[1],ipAddress[2],ipAddress[3]);

if(ipAddress[0]>=0 && ipAddress[0]<=127)
    printf("Class A Ip Address.\n");
if(ipAddress[0]>127 && ipAddress[0]<191)
    printf("Class B Ip Address.\n");
if(ipAddress[0]>191 && ipAddress[0]<224)
    printf("Class C Ip Address.\n");
if(ipAddress[0]>224 && ipAddress[0]<=239)
    printf("Class D Ip Address.\n");
if(ipAddress[0]>239)
    printf("Class E Ip Address.\n");

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably in addition to legacy IPv4 addresses support IPv6 in whatever you're trying to do. Also, IP classes have been deprecated and meaningless for a few decades already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran your code. The problem of `In the output negative values are being showed which are wrong.` can be solved by simply changing `short len=0;` to `unsigned short len=0;` and `char  oct[4]={0},cnt=0,cnt1=0,i,buf[5];` to `unsigned char  oct[4]={0},cnt=0,cnt1=0,i,buf[5];`.

An unsigned variable type of int can hold zero and positive numbers, and a signed int holds negative, zero and positive numbers.

In 32-bit integers, an unsigned integer has a range of 0 to 232-1 = 0 to 4,294,967,295 or about 4 billion. The signed version goes from -231-1 to 231, which is –2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 or about -2 billion to +2 billion. The range is the same, but it is shifted on the number line.

In the case of chars, which are only 1 byte, the range of an unsigned char is 0 to 256, while the range of a signed char is -127 to 127.

So your `void extractIpAddress(unsigned char *sourceString,short *ipAddress)` function should look something like this:

```
void extractIpAddress(unsigned char *sourceString,short *ipAddress)
 {
       unsigned short len=0;
       unsigned char  oct[4]={0},cnt=0,cnt1=0,i,buf[5];

       len=strlen(sourceString);
       for(i=0;i<len;i++)
       {
            if(sourceString[i]!='.'){
                buf[cnt++] =sourceString[i];
            }
            if(sourceString[i]=='.' || i==len-1){
                buf[cnt]='\0';
                cnt=0;
                oct[cnt1++]=atoi(buf);
       }
}
```

After changing the above variable to their correct type the program runs perfectly and gives the correct desired output.

Comment: A caution of the use of `atoi` anywhere. It provides *zero* error handling capability. In actual code you would want to use `strtoul` and validate the conversion and that the result was in the range of `unsigned char` before use.

Comment: the range of an unsigned char is 0..255, excluding 256

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach. Bring the correct data types and correct functions to scan and store those values. An example using `sscanf` below describes what I'm referring to.

- The source string should be native `char` types
- The initial `scanf` should be length limited. Better still, use `fgets`
- The result of `scanf` should be checked before diving into octet extraction.
- The target octets should be `unsigned char`
- Use [`sscanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), checking the result, to read the octets
- Use `%hhu` as the octet extraction format specifier. See [format specifiers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) for more information on ones you may not know exist or prove helpful.

The result looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int extractIpAddress(const char *sourceString, unsigned char *ip)
{
    return sscanf(sourceString, "%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu", ip, ip+1, ip+2, ip+3) == 4;
}

int main()
{
    char ip[20]={0};
    unsigned char ipAddress[4];
    int result = EXIT_FAILURE;

    printf("Enter IP Address (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx format): ");
    if (scanf("%19s", ip) == 1 && extractIpAddress(ip, ipAddress))
    {
        printf("\nIp Address: %hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu\n",
               ipAddress[0],ipAddress[1],ipAddress[2],ipAddress[3]);

        if(ipAddress[0]>=0 && ipAddress[0]<=127)
            printf("Class A Ip Address.\n");

        else if (ipAddress[0]>127 && ipAddress[0]<191)
            printf("Class B Ip Address.\n");

        else if (ipAddress[0]>191 && ipAddress[0]<224)
            printf("Class C Ip Address.\n");

        else if(ipAddress[0]>224 && ipAddress[0]<=239)
            printf("Class D Ip Address.\n");

        else
            printf("Class E Ip Address.\n");

        result = EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Nit, `ipAddress[0]>=0` is always true `:)` (`-Wtype-limits`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin his code; not mine. I concur regardless.